# Anomaly detection python

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, artificial-intelligence, outliers

I have a dataset with 7 parameters for each point:

- counterOfPackets
- counterOfSyn
- counterOfPa
- counterOfR
- counterOfRA
- counterOfFin
- packetsTotalSize

I would like to find a way to get all the outliers to a python list (not as a plt.show GUI).
What algorithm should I use and how can I view the results as a python list?
Thanks for your help :D

Comment: anomaly detection is a very wide field of research. could you explain your data or provide a definition for what an outlier or anomaly in your data would look like?

Comment: @sim Thanks for the quick replay.
I have network data that I sniffed and I want to be able to sort the data to several attacks like a syn flood, etc..
And of course, know what data is ok and which data is one of the attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This page on Medium from Will Badr is a good resource - https://towardsdatascience.com/5-ways-to-detect-outliers-that-every-data-scientist-should-know-python-code-70a54335a623. In terms of what outlier detection algorithm to use, the answer depends on the distribution of your data. I have found success using standard deviations and distance from inter-quartile ranges to identify outliers. However, these approaches work better over normal distributions, and in my scenario, I found methods to transform my data into a normal distribution without impacting the outcome.

Comment: I tried method 2 and I manage to get the box plot, but how can I take the data as a list? I have nothing to do with the visual image

Comment: Hey @Lidorelias3, you will need to replicate the logic used in the box plot, i.e., select rows that have values above or below 1.5 times the inter-quartile range, and the formula is explained again in the Medium article. You can use `scipy.stats.iqr` to calculate the inter-quartile range (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.iqr.html). Hope this helps.